# Apollo useMutation, onCompleted completion always returning true during Login Authentication?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, apollo, react-apollo

I am performing a GraphQL mutation to attempt login authentication however it returns true every time and stores a new user AuthToken, even when the login details are incorrect. It's very strange as when I run the GraphQL query in the IDE it works as it should. (ie. only succeeds when login/password are correct). I'm not sure how it is generating auth.Token and console.logs "onSuccess" regardless of what I put in the forms. Any help would be greatly appreciated, it's driving me crazy. Thank you.

```
const LOGIN_USER = gql `
mutation LoginUser {
    login (input: {
    clientMutationId:"uniqueId"
    username: "admin"
    password: "password"
    }) {
        authToken
            user {
                id
                name
            }
        }
}
`
const SignIn = (props) => {

const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)

const onLoginError = () => {
    console.log("onError")
} 

const onLoginSuccess = () => {
    console.log("onSuccess")
} 

const [loginUser, { loading, error }] = useMutation(LOGIN_USER, {
    onCompleted({login}) {
        localStorage.setItem('token', login.authToken)
        onLoginSuccess()
    },
    onError(error){
        alert(error)
        onLoginError()
    }
})

const onLoginSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    loginUser({ variables:
        {
            "input": {
                "clientMutationId": "uniqueId",
                "username": username,
                "password": password
            }
        }
    })
}
const handleOnChange = (event) => {
    if(event.target.name === "username") {
        setUsername(event.target.value)
    } else if(event.target.name === "password") {
        setPassword(event.target.value)
    }
}
return (
<form onSubmit={onLoginSubmit}>
<>
                        <input
                            className={styles.formInput}
                            name="username" 
                            placeholder="Username or email" 
                            type="text" 
                            value={username}
                            onChange={handleOnChange}
                        >
                        </input>
                        <input 
                            className={styles.formInput}
                            name="password"
                            placeholder="Password" 
                            type="password" 
                            value={password}
                            onChange={handleOnChange}
                        >
                        </input>
                        <button 
                            className="button is-primary is-pulled-right has-text-weight-semibold"
                            type="submit"
                            disabled={loading}
                        ><FiLogIn className={styles.loginIcon}/>
                            Login
                        </button>
                    </form>
</>
export default SignIn
```

Comment: Are you caching the query? Is the auth token different each time or the same token?

Comment: It's the same token each time. Is that bad?

Comment: When you run the same query using a different client (like Postman), is it a different token each time? You might be caching the query result on the front end. Pass the option "useCache": false , to the mutation. I'm not sure what library you're using, but instead of useCache, it could be "networkPolicy". Search the relevant docs about preventing query caching.

Comment: Actually sorry, it does change every time. I'm using Apollo here https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/ but I can't find any variables that turn Cache off.

I have clearStored and cookies however still no luck. I'm struggling to get Postman to process Mutations, seems to only do Queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query has hard-coded values for `username` and `password`, so they are going to result in a successful login each time, regardless of what is entered in your form. Any value you pass in for `variables` is effectively ignores since you're not actually using variables inside your query. Update your query to actually use the variables you are passing in (`username` and `password`).

Comment: Ahhhh oh my god, you have no idea I was racking my brains over this. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks Daniel!